# How to use other def values?

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I want to use other def values.
For example, I added a 'pt' in the 'clean_beds_process' definition and add 'Patients' in the 'run' definition.
I want to patient information when the 'clean_beds_process' function is called.
However, this makes this error 'AttributeError: type object 'Patients' has no attribute 'id''
I don't know why this happen.
Maybe I have something wrong understanding of mechanism of simpy.
Please let me know how can I use a patient information when 'clean_beds_process' function is called.
Thank you.

```
import simpy
import random

class Patients:
    def __init__(self, p_id):
        self.id = p_id
        self.bed_name = ""
        self.admission_decision = ""
    def admin_decision(self):
        admin_decision_prob = random.uniform(0, 1)
        if admin_decision_prob <= 0.7:
            self.admission_decision = "DIS"
        else:
            self.dmission_decision = "IU"
        return self.admission_decision

class Model:
    def __init__(self, run_number):
        self.env = simpy.Environment()
        self.pt_ed_q = simpy.Store(self.env )
        self.pt_counter = 0
        self.tg = simpy.Resource(self.env, capacity = 4)
        self.physician = simpy.Resource(self.env, capacity = 4)
        self.bed_clean = simpy.Store(self.env)
        self.bed_dirty = simpy.Store(self.env)
        self.IU_bed = simpy.Resource(self.env, capacity = 50)  
        
    def generate_beds(self):
        for i in range(77):
            yield self.env.timeout(0)
            yield self.bed_clean.put(f'bed{i}')
       
    def generate_pt_arrivals(self):
        while True:
            self.pt_counter += 1
            pt = Patients(self.pt_counter)
            yield self.env.timeout(5)
            self.env.process(self.process(pt))

    def clean_beds_process(self, cleaner_id, pt):
        while True:
            print(pt.id)
            bed = yield self.bed_dirty.get()
            yield self.env.timeout(50)
            yield self.bed_clean.put(bed)

    def process(self, pt):
        with self.tg.request() as req:
            yield req
            yield self.env.timeout(10)
        bed = yield self.bed_clean.get()
        pt.bed_name = bed
        pt.admin_decision()
        if pt.admission_decision == "DIS":
            with self.IU_bed.request() as req:
                dirty_bed_name = pt.bed_name
                yield self.bed_dirty.put(dirty_bed_name)
                yield self.env.timeout(600)
        else:
            dirty_bed_name = pt.bed_name
            yield self.bed_dirty.put(dirty_bed_name)

    def run(self):
        self.env.process(self.generate_pt_arrivals())
        self.env.process(self.generate_beds())
        for i in range(2):
            self.env.process(self.clean_beds_process(i+1, Patients))
        self.env.run(until = 650)

run_model = Model(0)
run_model.run()
```

Comment: self.env.process(self.clean_beds_process(i+1, Patients))

Patients is a class not a object instance.  No patients have yet to be created

Comment: Thank you Michael, I understand. Do you have any idea for using patient information (such as patient id and so on) when the function of "def clean_beds_process(self, cleaner_id, pt)" is called?

Comment: why would the cleaner need to know about patients?  If you are tracking bed stuff, then add a bed event log to each bed that tracks when a patient grabs a bed, releases a bed, and when a clean finishes cleaning a bed

Comment: Thank you Michael, I'm going to have the cleaner clean the bed beforehand. I'd like to compare with cleaning before patients arrivals and after patients arrivals. So the cleaner needs to know which IU the patient will go to so that the IU bed can be cleaned in advance. Is my explanation clear?

Comment: So if one patient enters and leave, you want that bed to stay dirty until the next patient shows up, even if the cleaner is idle?

Comment: are you trying to measure the patient wait time? or the time the bed spends dirty?

Comment: Yes, you expressed my thoughts exactly. Even if the bed is dirty, if there is no order to clean it, keep the cleaner's status as idle and clean it when asked to. And patients' waiting time should be collected basically all various experimental environments. In addition, if the hospital knows the patient information in advance and clean the IU bed in advance, the patient's waiting time will be reduced a little, so I'm going to experiment with how much it will be. Thank you for your time and work!!!

Comment: If you have any idea for solving this or any comment, please let me know. I'm still stuck in this and can not move forward. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if a patient can use either a clean bed or a dirty bed then the patient needs to make two request (one for each type of bed) and use env.any_of to wait for the first request to fire.  You also need to deal with the case that both events fire at the same time.  Don't forget to cancel the request you do not use.  If the request that fires is for a clean bed, things stay mostly the same.  But if the request is for a dirty bed, then you need to add a step to clean the bed.  For this I would make the cleaners Resources instead of processes.  So the patient would request a cleaner, and do a timeout for the cleaning time, release the cleaner.  To collect patient data I would create a log with the patient id, key event, time, and crunch these post sim to get the stats I need.  To process the log I often create a dataframe that filters the log for the first, a second dataframe that filters for the second envent,  join the two dataframes on patient id.  Now both events for a patient is on one row so I can get the delta.  once I have have the delta I can do a sum and count.  For example, if my two events are when a patient arrives, and when a patient gets a bed, get the sum of deltas and divide by the count and I have the average time to bed.

If you remember, one of the first answers I gave you awhile ago had a example to get the first available bed from two different queues

I do not have a lot of time right know, but I hope this dissertation helps a bit

Comment: Hi, Michael. I tried to build a little different model, but there is a issue. Please please see the attached link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72049192/what-happens-if-i-using-env-process-whenever-i-need-it