# What happens if I using 'env.process()' whenever I need it?

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I'd like to have a bed cleaner only when necessary. The error does not occur as shown in the code below, but the result is not accurate. Increasing or decreasing the number of cleaner should change the results, but the result is the same regardless of the change in the number of cleaner.
Maybe I can guess, whenever I use 'env.process()' the "self.bed_cleaner" is reset. So, cleaner is always idle... but I'm not sure.
What do you think I don't understand? Please help me I can experiment properly.

```
import simpy
import random

class Pre_define:
    ed_bed_cleaning_request = True

class Patients:
    def __init__(self, p_id):
        self.id = p_id
        self.edbed_name = ""
        self.iubed_name = ""
        self.admission_decision = ""
        self.wtime_bed_NotClean = float("nan")
    def admin_decision(self):
        if (self.id % 2) == 0: # even dis, else IU 50%
            self.admission_decision = "DIS"
        else:
            self.admission_decision = "IU"
        return self.admission_decision

class Model:
    def __init__(self, run_number):
        self.env = simpy.Environment()
        self.pt_ed_q = simpy.Store(self.env )
        self.pt_counter = 0
        self.tg = simpy.Resource(self.env, capacity = 4)
        self.physician = simpy.Resource(self.env, capacity = 4)
        self.edbed_clean = simpy.Store(self.env, capacity = 4)
        self.iubed_clean = simpy.Store(self.env, capacity = 4)
        self.bed_dirty = simpy.Store(self.env, capacity = 8)
        self.bed_cleaner = simpy.Resource(self.env, capacity = 1)
    def generate_beds(self):
        for i in range(4):
            yield self.env.timeout(0)
            yield self.edbed_clean.put(f'edbed{i}')
            yield self.iubed_clean.put(f'iubed{i}')
    def generate_pt_arrivals(self):
        while True:
            pt = Patients(self.pt_counter)
            yield self.env.timeout(5)
            self.env.process(self.process(pt))
            self.pt_counter += 1            
    def clean_beds_process(self, pt):
        bed = yield self.bed_dirty.get()
        while True:
            if (Pre_define.ed_bed_cleaning_request == True and bed[:2] == 'ed') or (Pre_define.ed_bed_cleaning_request == False and bed[:2] == 'iu'):
                with self.bed_cleaner.request() as bedreq:
                    yield bedreq
                yield self.env.timeout(30)
                if bed[:2] == 'ed':
                    yield self.edbed_clean.put(bed)
                else:
                    yield self.iubed_clean.put(bed)
                break
            elif (Pre_define.ed_bed_cleaning_request == False and bed[:2] == 'ed') or (Pre_define.ed_bed_cleaning_request == True and bed[:2] == 'iu'):
                with self.bed_cleaner.request() as bedreq:
                    yield bedreq
                yield self.env.timeout(30)
                if bed[:2] == 'ed':
                    yield self.edbed_clean.put(bed)
                else:
                    yield self.iubed_clean.put(bed)
            else:
                break

    def process(self, pt):
        with self.tg.request() as req:
            yield req
            yield self.env.timeout(10)
        if self.edbed_clean.items == [] and self.bed_dirty.items != []:
            Pre_define.ed_bed_cleaning_request = True
            self.env.process(self.clean_beds_process(pt))                 # =========> This part I use env.process() for call cleaner
        elif self.edbed_clean.items == [] and self.bed_dirty.items == []:
            self.env.process(self.clean_beds_process(pt))
            Pre_define.ed_bed_cleaning_request = True
        else:
            Pre_define.ed_bed_cleaning_request = True
        edbed = yield self.edbed_clean.get()
        pt.edbed_name = edbed
        pt.admin_decision()
        if pt.admission_decision != "DIS":
            if self.iubed_clean.items == [] and self.bed_dirty.items != []:
                Pre_define.ed_bed_cleaning_request = False
                self.env.process(self.clean_beds_process(pt))            # =========> This part I use env.process() for call cleaner
            elif self.iubed_clean.items == [] and self.bed_dirty.items == []:
                self.env.process(self.clean_beds_process(pt)) 
                Pre_define.ed_bed_cleaning_request = False
            else:
                Pre_define.ed_bed_cleaning_request = False
            iubed = yield self.iubed_clean.get()
            pt.iubed_name = iubed
            dirty_edbed_name = pt.edbed_name
            yield self.bed_dirty.put(dirty_edbed_name)
            yield self.env.timeout(60)  # IU bed occupied time
            dirty_iubed_name = pt.iubed_name
            yield self.bed_dirty.put(dirty_iubed_name)
        else:
            dirty_bed_name = pt.edbed_name
            yield self.bed_dirty.put(dirty_bed_name)
    def run(self):
        self.env.process(self.generate_beds())
        self.env.process(self.generate_pt_arrivals())
        self.env.run(until = 200)

run_model = Model(0)
run_model.run()
```

Comment: in 
def clean_beds_process(self, pt)

why are you passing in a patient, the bed cleaner wants a bed.

in def process(self, pt):  request both a clean and dirty bed and use the first request that gets filled.  Note both request could fill at the same time.  If that bed is dirty, pass the bed to the cleaner.  Also note that you will need to cancel the request that does not fill.

Comment: why is there a while loop in def clean_beds_process(self, pt):  don't you want just one bed to be cleaned?

Comment: Maybe it's my problem that I can't answer your question properly. It seems that it happened because the lack of understanding of the simpy.
Anyway, what I intended for the function you mentioned is as follows.
1. All beds are classified to ED beds and IU beds.
2. All dirty beds(ED, IU beds) enter one queue and are cleaned according to the their arrival

Comment: 3. If there is no clean bed in the ED when a patient arrive and it is time for the ED bed to be cleaned from the queue, the bed is cleaned and add cleaned ED bed list. (IU beds also the same) 
4. On the contrary, if there is no clean bed in ED when a patient arrive, and an IU bed should be cleaned from queue, clean the IU bed and put it on the IU bed clean list. And then Continue cleaning until the ED bed comes out.
(The same as IU bed case)

Comment: So, I thought that the 'while' is for keep cleaning for matching arrived patient request (ED request should be matched ED bed, IU request should be matched IU bed).. Please let me know if my explanation is unclear.

Comment: sounds like the cleaner needs to clean what ever is in the dirty queue and put the clean bed in a either a clean ed, or clean iu bed queue based on bed type.  No requests needed.  Which is a small change from the last working version

Comment: also you do not need to yield when your request a bed.  You can get the bed request, do your triage, then yield on the request.  If the bed came while doing triage, the yield will take 0 time.  Getting the bed starts when you make the request, not when you do the yield.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. Yes, your understanding is correct. Maybe because lack of my understanding, I'm not fully following you. Anyway, you mean, I don't have to use "while" and "self.env.process(self.clean_beds_process(pt))". Just use request right? I will try it again and if you don't mind, may I ask again? I have to finish this model as soon as possible because this is not the final goal of my research. Thank you so much!!

Comment: When I was trying to modify the code, I remembered the first time I asked the question, when I only used 'request', it throw an infinite loop result. This reason was looks like waiting of cleaning bed or dirty bed after a patient leave stuck another event, so any events couldn't move forward. Therefore, made 'cleaner' function and put the function at 'process 'self.env.process(self.clean_beds_process(pt))'. So, I think if I use only 'request', maybe it stuck another event.... what do you think about this?

Comment: The problem with this code is that even if I changed the number of cleaners, the results are always the same. What I mean is that if there is one cleaner, it takes time a lot, but many cleaner there is no waiting. However,  There is always no waiting time regardless of the number of cleaners. I'm using the cleaner as a resource with 'self' to inherit the attribute, but I'm curious why it's being renewed without maintaining the condition.

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried to use 'anyof' and you recommended, but still can not solve the problem. Please help me how to get the results by cleaner numbers. Also, I have a question about your answer.  In the first code which you answered, " for _ in range(2):        env.process(clean_beds(env, dirty_bed_q, clean_bed_q)) ",  the number of range, 2, means that the number of bed cleaner, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patients only get clean beds.  Both EU and IU beds are being cleaned.  Both types of dirty beds are put into one common bed cleaning queue.  The cleaners are smart enough to put eu beds in the eu clean bed queue and iu beds into the clean iu bed queue.  Also reduced the iu treatment time to get dirty iu beds to show up sooner in the log.  Bed is now a class with a id and type.  Otherwise this is the same program from a couple of questions ago

```
"""
    Hospital bed sim 3
    Patient arrives,
    gets trianged,
    gets a clean eu bed from clean eu bed queue
    leaves eu bed which is queued for cleaning beds
    if admitted get iu bed from clean iu bed queue
    gets treated
    leaves, puting the iu bed in the queue for cleaning.

    bed cleaners wait for beds to show up in cleaning queue
    both eu and iu beds are in the same queue
    after cleaning a bed it is put into is clean bed queue
    (clean eu beds go to the clean eu queue, clean iu beds go to the clean iu queue)

    Programer Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

class Pre_Define:
    warmup_period = 1440
    sim_duration = 14400
    number_of_runs = 1 #3
    eu_beds= 77
    iu_beds=50

class Bed():
    """
        Hosptial beds, can have two types emergency (eu) and inpatiient (iu)
    """
    def __init__(self, id, type):
        self.id = id
        self.type = type

class Patients:
    """
        enity model is processing
        uses beds
    """
    def __init__(self, p_id):
        self.id = p_id
        self.bed = None
        self.admission_decision = ""

    def admin_decision(self):
        """
            decides if a eu patient becmes a iu patient
        """
        admin_decision_prob = random.uniform(0, 1)
        if admin_decision_prob <= 0.7:
            self.admission_decision = "DIS"
        else:
            self.dmission_decision = "IU"

        return self.admission_decision

    
class Model:
    def __init__(self, run_number):
        self.env = simpy.Environment()
        self.pt_ed_q = simpy.Store(self.env )
        self.pt_counter = 0
        self.tg = simpy.Resource(self.env, capacity = 4)
        self.physician = simpy.Resource(self.env, capacity = 4)
        self.iu_bed_clean = simpy.Store(self.env)
        self.eu_bed_clean = simpy.Store(self.env)
        self.bed_dirty = simpy.Store(self.env)

        self.run_number = run_number
        
    def generate_beds(self):
        """
            create the clean eu and iu beds
        """
        self.eu_bed_clean.items = [Bed(i+1, "EU") for i in range(Pre_Define.eu_beds)]
        self.iu_bed_clean.items = [Bed(i+1, "IU") for i in range(Pre_Define.iu_beds)]
       
    def generate_pt_arrivals(self):
        while True:
            self.pt_counter += 1
            pt = Patients(self.pt_counter)
            #yield self.env.timeout(1/7)
            yield self.env.timeout(5)
            self.env.process(self.ed_process(pt))

    def clean_beds_process(self, cleaner_id):
        """
            contious process for cleaning beds
            feeds off of the dirty bed queue
            if the queue is empty, will wait 
            until a bed is added to the queue.
            Clean beds are returned to the clean bed queue

            This process is the cleaner.  
            It one instance of th process is started for each cleaner

            both eu and iu dirty beds are put into the same queue fifo
            cleaner puts the clean bed in the right clean bed queue
        """

        while True:

            # wait untile there is a bed in the dirty bead queue
            bed = yield self.bed_dirty.get()

            print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}  cleaner {cleaner_id} has started to clean bed {bed.type} {bed.id}')

            # clean bed
            yield self.env.timeout(50)

            print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}  cleaner {cleaner_id} has finish cleaning bed {bed.type} {bed.id}')

            # put bed in the right clean bed queue base on type, loop to wait for next dirty bead
            if bed.type == 'EU':
                yield self.eu_bed_clean.put(bed)
            else:
                yield self.iu_bed_clean.put(bed)


    def ed_process(self, pt):
        # process for treating a patient

        print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}  patient  {pt.id} has arrived')
        with self.tg.request() as req:
            yield req
            triage_service_time = random.expovariate(1.0/18)
            yield self.env.timeout(triage_service_time)
        
        print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}  patient  {pt.id} has been triaged')
        
        # yield self.pt_ed_q.put(Patients.id)
        # pt_id = yield self.pt_ed_q.get()
        # Bed_Mgmt.check_q(pt_id, self.pt_ed_q, self.bed_clean, self.bed_dirty, self.bed_cleaner)

        bed = yield self.eu_bed_clean.get()
        pt.bed = bed
        print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}  patient {pt.id} has a clean bed {bed.type} {bed.id}')

        with self.physician.request() as req:
            yield req
            yield self.env.timeout(10)
            pt.admin_decision()

            print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}  patient {pt.id} has admission descesion of  {pt.admission_decision}')
            

        if pt.admission_decision == "DIS":
            # get iu bed
            bed = yield self.iu_bed_clean.get()
            
            # move patient to new bed
            yield self.bed_dirty.put(pt.bed)
            print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}  patient {pt.id} moved to IU giving up bed {pt.bed.type} {pt.bed.id} and taking bed {bed.type} {bed.id}')
            pt.bed = bed
           
             # time until IU bed becomes becone available 
            yield self.env.timeout(60)
            yield self.bed_dirty.put(pt.bed)
            print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}  patient {pt.id} left IU giving up bed {pt.bed.type} {pt.bed.id}')
        else:
            # patient leaves hospital
            yield self.bed_dirty.put(pt.bed)
            print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}  patient {pt.id} left EU giving up bed {pt.bed.type} {pt.bed.id}')


    def run(self):
        self.env.process(self.generate_pt_arrivals())
        self.generate_beds()

        # creating and starting two cleaners
        for i in range(2):
            self.env.process(self.clean_beds_process(i+1))
        
        #self.env.run(until = Pre_Define.warmup_period + Pre_Define.sim_duration)
        self.env.run(until = 650)

for run in range(Pre_Define.number_of_runs):
    run_model = Model(run)
    run_model.run()
    print()
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I have a question. If the cleaner do not get order to clean a dirty 
bed, the cleaner should be idle even if there is a dirty bed. If I understand this process properly, if there is a dirty bed, it is to be cleaned it regardless of the request to clean, right? Starting with this code that you helped me with, I'll have to think a little bit more about how I can make what I said above. Anyway, thank you so much and you always helpful to me. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi, Michael, I have a question about making patient queue at the beginning of 'ed_process'. Do you have any idea of how to get all of patients into the queue as soon as they arrive at the ED and then service a patient at 'ed_process' one by one? I know it is already implemented but if I want to add a queue for all patients, how can I implement?

Comment: The purpose of this implementation is that I must check a patient's information before cleaning the bed.

Comment: put   req = self.eu_bed_clean.get()   at the top of the process and change   bed = yield self.eu_bed_clean.get()   to bed = yield req    The get will put the patient in the queue, but you code will keep going until it gets to the yield.

Comment: Thank you Michael!!, I added more logic and modified some of it in the code you answered me last time. If you have time, please take a look at my new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133771/how-can-i-keep-track-of-the-information-of-multiple-objects-where-there-are-vari